# cocoalibspotify SPTrack to NSData

Tags: nsdata, bonjour, cocoalibspotify-2.0

I need to send an SPTrack to another device via an Bonjour connection. But the bonjour library I am using(DTBonjour) requires an encodeWithCoder implementation to send objects across a network. 
But it seems like SPTrack does not include the NSCoding implementation, so I don't want to mess around in the spotify library, my question is: Can I somehow create a NSData object from SPTrack without SPTrack implementing NSCoding?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spotify tracks aren't really suited to be directly sent between processes like this - they represent a track from the perspective of a logged-in user and contain a lot of state.

Instead, you should take the `spotifyURL` of the track and transmit that. In your other process, use `[SPTrack trackForTrackURL: …]` to recreate a valid `SPTrack` instance.